# How do I get 4 images on same line

Tags: html, css

How do I get the four little icons on the same line without interfering with the **" account since"** line? The images keep going on the top-right of that line. I want to create a separate line for these four images and they need to all be on that same line no matter the screen size.

Also, how do I stop the **" account since"** line from being responsive as in the sense that the font changes size when you change screen size?

```css
.section {
 background-color: #5ECCBA;
 margin-left: 1%;
 margin-right: 1%;
 width: 97%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 height: 250px;
 margin-top: 85px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
}

.section img {
 display: inline-block;
}

#ProfilePic {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

h2 {
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: -70px;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.accsince {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 margin-top: -30px;
 margin-left: 30%;
 font-weight:lighter;
}

.inline-block {
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 margin-left:5%;
 margin-top: 5%;
}

#map {
 width:100%;
 height:400px;
 background:white;
 margin-top:15px;
 margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
<img src="img/Linda Profile.png" id="ProfilePic" alt="profile picture" height="40%">
 <h2>Linda *lastname*</h2>
 <p class="accsince">Account since Nov. 7th 2012</p><!--random date-->
 
<div class="inline-block">
 <img src="img/002-big-map-placeholder-outlined-symbol-of-interface.png" alt="add trip" height="20px"></div>
<div class="inline-block">
 <img src="img/004-recycling-bin.png" alt="delete account" height="20px"></div>
<div class="inline-block">
 <img src="img/001-megaphone-outline-of-amplification-tool.png" alt="share account" height="20px"></div>
<div class="inline-block">
 <img src="img/003-add-square-outlined-interface-button.png" alt="add pictures" height="20px"></div>
</div><!--End section-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added  as a container div for all icons (images) that needs to be on separate row and added class clear to it. It clears entire row.

```
    .section {
     background-color: #5ECCBA;
     margin-left: 1%;
     margin-right: 1%;
     width: 97%;
     white-space: nowrap;
     height: 250px;
     margin-top: 85px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     float: left;
     display: block;
    }

    .section img {
     display: inline-block;
    }

    #ProfilePic {
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
    }

    h2 {
     display: inline;
     margin-left: 5%;
     margin-top: -70px;
     text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .accsince {
     float: left;
     display: inline;
     margin-top: -30px;
     margin-left: 30%;
     font-weight:lighter;
    }

    .inline-block {
     display:inline-block;
     float:left;
     margin-left:5%;
     margin-top: 5%;
    }

    #map {
     width:100%;
     height:400px;
     background:white;
     margin-top:15px;
     margin-bottom: 70px;
    }
.clear{
clear:both;
}
    <div class="section">
    <img src="img/Linda Profile.png" id="ProfilePic" alt="profile picture" height="40%">
     <h2>Linda *lastname*</h2>
     <p class="accsince">Account since Nov. 7th 2012<`enter code here`/p><!--random date-->
     <div class="clear">
    <div class="inline-block">
     <img src="img/002-big-map-placeholder-outlined-symbol-of-interface.png" alt="add trip" height="20px"></div>
    <div class="inline-block">
     <img src="img/004-recycling-bin.png" alt="delete account" height="20px"></div>
    <div class="inline-block">
     <img src="img/001-megaphone-outline-of-amplification-tool.png" alt="share account" height="20px"></div>
    <div class="inline-block">
     <img src="img/003-add-square-outlined-interface-button.png" alt="add pictures" height="20px"></div></div>
    </div><!--End section-->
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know how I can stop the "account since Nov. 7th..." from going bigger when the screen size goes wider?

Comment: I don't see that happening. Are you increasing text-size while testing?

Comment: Hmm.. When I put my screen from "mobile" to laptop size it grows way out of proportion, messing with the whole layout

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't experience the same. Verified in Chrome developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simplified example. Hope it helps.

I'd strongly suggest using Bootstrap grid system. It's easy to work with and most importantly it is RESPONSIVE.

here is the [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.wrapper{
  width:80%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.pics {
  text-align: center;
}
.inline {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pics">
      <div class="inline">HELLO1</div>
      <div class="inline">HELLO2</div>
      <div class="inline">HELLO3</div>
      <div class="inline">HELLO4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have no idea why I didn't think of Bootstrap in this case.. I made them all col-3!

Comment: you are welcome. generally when people answer your question, you should either upvote their answer (if it benefits you), and/or mark is as answered, this way the question is closed.